# Interface instantiation vs class instantiation

Tags: c#, interface

Could someone please helpme to understand if the following codes are same. If not what's the difference between class and interfance instantiation.

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer()
UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer()
```

As far as I understand Inteface has only method signature and if the interface has been implemented by 3 classes. Not too sure which of the 3 instance would be created by first statement above.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Interfaces can't be instantiated by definition. You always instantiate a concrete class.

So in *both* statements your instance is actually of type `UnityContainer`.

The difference is for the first statement, as far as C# is concerned, your `container` is something that implements `IUnityContainer`, which might have an API different from `UnityContainer`.

---

Consider:

```
interface IAnimal 
{
    void die();
}

class Cat : IAnimal 
{
    void die() { ... }
    void meow() { ... }
}
```

Now :

```
IAnimal anAnimal = new Cat();
Cat aCat= new Cat();
```

C# knows for sure `anAnimal.die()` works, because `die()` is defined in `IAnimal`. But it won't let you do `anAnimal.meow()` even though it's a `Cat`, whereas `aCat` can invoke both methods.

When you use the interface as your type you are, in a way, losing information.

However, if you had another class `Dog` that also implements `IAnimal`, your `anAnimal` could reference a `Dog` instance as well. That's the power of an interface; you can give them any class that implements it.

Comment: There's one exceptional case when you *can* instantiate an interface: when it's a COM interface.

Comment: Nice! I'm sure that your words "losing information" do not intend to demote using interfaces.

Comment: @Gert Trying to make it easy to understand... The result is more convoluted that I had hoped.

Comment: @Reed, yeah, but syntactically, it looks like interface instantiation.

Comment: Thanks @NullUserException, simple example and good explanation. Had to accept your answer although all answers are valid. Thank you all for your answers, much appreciate it.

Comment: If a class implements an interface that provides all the functionality one will need from the class, it's often better to pass parameters of the interface type than of the class type, since the latter will allow routines to be used interchangeably with either the original class or any other class which implements the interface.  Once one starts passing interface types as parameters, any field that gets loaded from such a parameter will itself have to be declared as the interface type.  It's often simplest to just use the interface type for everything but the invocation of the constructor.

Comment: I understood your point, but can you please give me a real life example when to use interface as a type to create object rather than using the class?

Answer (score 5):

There's really no such thing as "interface instantiation", but there are interface variables. The first line is an example of one such variable.

With the first line, you could instantiate `container` to be any concrete class that implements `IUnityContainer`. With the second line, the `container` object could only be instantiated from the `UnityContainer` class or a derived class.

When you use interface variables in your code, it allows you to more easily switch out the concrete implementation, which makes your code more flexible.

Comment: That's not really true. `UnityContainer` implements `IUnityContainer`, so you can pass the second variable to methods accepting `IUnityContainer` as well.

Comment: The second version could be certainly used with methods that take `IUnityContainer` as their parameter. If a class implements some interface, it's implicitly convertible to that interface.

Comment: Also, the second `container` might not be *just* `UnityContainer`. It might be also any derived class.

Answer (score 2):

Interface instantiation is not possible. But when we created an an object for interface using its implemented class it works.

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer()// It is assigning an object of its implemented class.
UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer() // To access directly by using like this.
```

Assume that there is a multiple inheritance, to achieve this we need to go with first.

There is no need to provide such things we go with second way.

Interfaces restricts direct access of the data and members of its class.

Comment: "Interfaces restricts direct access of the data and members of its class." Why would I want to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

The object instantiated and stored in the `IUnityContainer container` variable is considered by the compiler to have only the members defined in the `IUnityContainer` interface.  That is, if the `UnityContainer` class contains members that aren't defined by the `IUnityContainer` interface, you won't be able to invoke them.  On the other hand, you could "put" any object that implements the `IUnityContainer` interface in the `IUnityContainer container` variable--not just instances of `UnityContainer`.  With the second declaration, you're stuck with instances of `UnityContainer` and objects in its inheritance hierarchy.

Check out the [C# Programming Guide to Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) for more information on interfaces and how they're used.

Comment: When you said “properties”, you probably meant “members”.