# In C#, the interface can be instantiated?

Tags: c#, interface

I'm reading the code in [*here*](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30721/WPF-TreeListView-Control). I find that `private ITreeModel _model;` in TreeList.cs:

```
namespace Aga.Controls.Tree
{
    public class TreeList: ListView
    {
        #region Properties
        //...
        private ITreeModel _model;
        public ITreeModel Model
        {
            //...
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

and the ITreeModel is a interface in ITreeModel.cs:

```
namespace Aga.Controls.Tree
{
    public interface ITreeModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get list of children of the specified parent
        /// </summary>
        IEnumerable GetChildren(object parent);

        /// <summary>
        /// returns wheather specified parent has any children or not.
        /// </summary>
        bool HasChildren(object parent);
    }
}
```

the `_model` is a instantiated object?

**Edited**:

`TreeList.cs`:

```
namespace Aga.Controls.Tree
{
    public class TreeList: ListView
    {
        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Internal collection of rows representing visible nodes, actually displayed in the ListView
        /// </summary>
        internal ObservableCollectionAdv<TreeNode> Rows
        {
            get;
            private set;
        } 

        private ITreeModel _model;
        public ITreeModel Model
        {
            get { return _model; }
            set 
            {
                if (_model != value)
                {
                    _model = value;
                    _root.Children.Clear();
                    Rows.Clear();
                    CreateChildrenNodes(_root);
                }
            }
        }

        private TreeNode _root;
        internal TreeNode Root
        {
            get { return _root; }
        }
        //....
    }
}
```

}

**Edited2**:

Somewhere:

```
public partial class RegistrySample : UserControl
{
    public RegistrySample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _tree.Model = new RegistryModel();
    }
}
```

`class RegistryModel : ITreeModel`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211571/interface-instantiation-vs-class-instantiation for more information on this subject.

Comment: Why doing this is even useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can do this, but underlying object must implement this Interface. So you can do something like

```
ITreeModel _model  = new TreeModel();
```

Where

```
public class TreeModel:ITreeModel
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can never instantiate an interface in C# directly, but yes you can instantiate a subclass implementing that interface. For example:

```
interface IShape
{
   //Method Signature
   void area(int r);
}

public class Circle : IShape
{
   //method Implementation
   void area(int r)
   {
      float area;
      area = 3.14 * r * r;
      Console.WriteLine("The area of the circle is: {0}",area);
   }
}

public class Shapes
{
   public static void Main() {
      //Uncommenting the following line will cause compiler error as the  
      // line tries to create an instance of interface.
      // interface i = new IShape();

     // We can have references of interface type.
     IShape i = new Circle();
     i.area(10);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's implemented somewhere else in the code. If you call `_model.GetType().ToString()` you will see it is not just an interface.

But to answer your question correctly, YES, an interface can be instantiated. Some of you may think "no it can't", but it **can be done** (with some COM hacks):

```
class Foo : IFoo
{
    readonly string name;
    public Foo(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    string IFoo.Message
    {
        get
        {
            return "Hello from " + name;
        }
    }
}
// these attributes make it work
// (the guid is purely random)
[ComImport, CoClass(typeof(Foo))]
[Guid("d60908eb-fd5a-4d3c-9392-8646fcd1edce")]
interface IFoo
{
    string Message {get;}
}
//and then somewhere else:
IFoo foo = new IFoo(); //no errors!
```

[Here is my source.](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/who-says-you-cant-instantiate-interface.html)

Comment: Won't `foo.GetType()` be `Foo`, a class type?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen It will, but it's still pretty interesting :P

Comment: Well, maybe, but it is just a fancy syntax for creating an instance with runtime type `Foo`, a class type. I would be more shocked if you created an object such that `.GetType().IsInterface` was true. But I didn't know this [`CoClassAttribute` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.coclassattribute.aspx).

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance It's a COM interface and it's a exceptional case, svick said in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211571/interface-instantiation-vs-class-instantiation

Answer (score 0):

That `_model` should contain an instance of a class that *implements* that `ITreeModel` interface (or it's `null`).

Comment: Correct. Or contain a _boxed_ value of a `struct` that implements the interface (which you might consider a special case of what you already mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

From [`Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/ms173156.aspx)

> An interface can't be instantiated directly. Its members are
>   implemented by any class or struct that implements the interface.

Comment: It can be... kind of: http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/who-says-you-cant-instantiate-interface.html

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Because I'm at work now, I can't access blogspot sites but I read it later.

Answer (score 0):

No _model is an **interface reference** to instance of a **class object** which **implements** ITreeModel

Answer (score 0):

`_model` is a member of `TreeList` and that means that you can create an instance of a class and then it will contain an instance of some class. for example

```
_model = new TreeModel();
```

will make `_model` contain an instance

but you cannot do

```
_model = new ITreeModel();
```

because `ITreeModel` is and interface and you cannot create an instance of an interface