# When to use Interface variable = new class variable OOP

Tags: c#, oop

i saw often people use this code like

```
interface IAnimal 
{
    void die();
}

class Cat : IAnimal 
{
    void die() { ... }
    void meow() { ... }
}

IAnimal anAnimal = new Cat();
Cat aCat= new Cat();
```

C# knows for sure anAnimal.die() works, because die() is defined in IAnimal. But it won't let you do anAnimal.meow() even though it's a Cat, whereas aCat can invoke both methods.

so tell me why & when we should write this kind of code

```
IAnimal anAnimal = new Cat();
```

what is the advantage ??

thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about broad, general programming concepts. This question belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Kind of explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7211580/122005)

Comment: Downvote because the question is just copied and a little bit changed from the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7211580/2655508

Comment: @Heslacher, yes, there should be a reference to it in the question. As there is no reference, it looks more like an attempt to ask *popular* question. His  last [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21902878/1997232) is also following same pattern.

Comment: By the way, .NET classes aren't variables as far as I know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interface instantiation vs class instantiation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211571/interface-instantiation-vs-class-instantiation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If `anAnimal` could also be assigned a different implementation of `IAnimal`, this is necessary.
2. If the code that uses `anAnimal` isn't `Cat`-specific, this is probably a good idea to make the code more generic and reusable.