# How interface can be instantiate this way

Tags: c#, oop, interface

from a url i saw people can instantiate interface like this way

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new IFoo(1);
        foo.Do();
    }
}

[
    ComImport, 
    Guid("C906C002-B214-40d7-8941-F223868B39A5"), 
    CoClass(typeof(FooImpl))
]
public interface IFoo
{
    void Do();
}

public class FooImpl : IFoo
{
    private readonly int i;

    public FooImpl(int i)
    {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);   
    }
}
```

how it is possible to write like this `var foo = new IFoo(1);` looking for guidance. thanks

Comment: It isn't. I suggest stopping asking all those interface question and read some material about interfaces and polymorphism in C#.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303717/newing-up-interfaces?rq=1

Comment: @Samuel It *does* work.

Comment: Even if possible, this would just make the whole `interface` idea useless, the big question is: Why would you *ever* want to do this?

Comment: @Thomas: did you follow the [documentation guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708954.aspx) about adding a reference to a COM object?

Comment: @dcastro This was indeed new to me. Thomas please accept my apology on the first sentence. I've learnt something new today. Beside COM specific attributes this is not a common approach when working with interfaces. And I still recommend concentrating on base interface concepts introduction.

Comment: Looks like he's asking about the code from [Instantiating interfaces - Ayande](http://ayende.com/blog/4121/instantiating-interfaces).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's just how COM works. You've declared `FooImpl` to be `IFoo`'s coclass. `new IFoo(1);` will be compiled to `new FooImpl(1);`

According to §17.5 of the C# specification, attributes under the `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace may break all the rules. This is specific to Microsoft's C# implementation.

Marc Gravell and Jon Skeet have really good blog posts about this: [Who says you can’t instantiate an interface?](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/who-says-you-cant-instantiate-interface.html) and [Faking COM to fool the C# compiler](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/07/07/faking-com-to-fool-the-c-compiler.aspx)