# Object#CreateInstance misunderstanding in .NET

Tags: c#

I know you can't instantiate an abstract class, but C# looks like it's doing that. I think I'm just having some trouble with the syntax. Here's the example:

```
public abstract class AClass {
...
}

public class SomeClass:AClass{
...
}

public class SomeOtherClass{
  public static AClass createInstance(string key){
    AClass instance = Object.CreateInstance<SomeClass>();
    return instance;
  }
}
```

When I call `SomeOtherClass.createInstance("key")` everything works fine. However, if you look closely it looks like `AClass` is instantiated. Can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: He's creating an instance of `SomeClass` and casting it to `AClass`

Comment: would this make it any clear? `AClass instance = new SomeClass();`

Comment: I think I'm having the most trouble understanding what `AClass instance = Object.CreateInstance<SomeClass>();` is doing.

Comment: without seeing the definition of CreateInstance method we can only guess

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interface instantiation vs class instantiation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211571/interface-instantiation-vs-class-instantiation)

Comment: It's just like any other question here but instead of using `new SomeClass()` you wrap it as `Object.CreateInstance<SomeClass>()`. If you know basic C# then you know what this does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is not instantiating an abstract class - it is instantiating a class that *extends* an abstract class.

It is equivalent to

```
AClass instance = new SomeClass();
```

The assignment is valid, because `SomeClass` is a *subclass* of `AClass`. Since inheritance models the "is-a" relationship, it is always allowed to make an assignment of an instance of a subclass to a variable typed as a superclass or an interface.

Answer (score 1):

There's a variable of type "reference to `AClass`" which refers to the `AClass` subobject inside a complete object of type `SomeClass`.

Abstract class instances can only exist as base subobjects.  This code does nothing to violate that rule.