# explanation of INameOfInterface nameOfVariable = new ExampleClass();

Tags: c#

I will appreciate if someone could explain the following C# code

```
INameOfInterface nameOfVariable = new ExampleClass();
```

ExampleClass is implementing interface INameOfInterface.
What is this line doing? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: This line initializes an instance of `ExampleClass();`, referencing it with a variable of type `INameOfInterface`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211571/interface-instantiation-vs-class-instantiation or any C#-book.

Answer (score 0):

The line is creating an instance of ExampleClass and assigning it to a variable of type INameOfInterface.

Answer (score 0):

It initializes instance of `ExampleClass` type and assigns it to `nameOfVariable` variable.

`ExampleClass` implements `INameOfInterface` interface.

Answer (score 0):

It's doing three things at the same time.

1. It's defining a variable called `nameOfVariable`. Its type is `INameOfInterface`, which means that anything that implements `INameOfInterface` can be put there. Any code using it can assume that what it contains is either something that implements `INameOfInterface` or else is null. This means that any of the properties or methods defined in `INameOfInterface` can be called on it.
2. Creating a new object of type `ExampleClass`.
3. Putting that new object in that variable.